# International phone number format regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I am trying to validate phone number for international format.

```
^(\+\d{2})*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$
```

Valid Numbers should be in `+649916123764` format (`64` can be replaced by any 2 digits)

But my expression is accepting `+649916123764` and `9916123764`.

How to control first 3 digits should be in +2 digits followed by 10 numbers?

Comment: Remove the `*`: [`^(\+\d{2})(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$`](http://goo.gl/yP9tBx). Is it what you need?

Comment: Agree with @stribizhev, make it `.` instead `*` specially when it is after `)` and the optional part `[-.` should go with `?` instead `*`

Comment: @stribizhev: Thank you , understood